# How can I stow away on a submarine?

Tags: travel

What is the best way to sneak on board a submarine? Where could a person hide? It's okay if my stowaway is eventually discovered but I would like them to remain hidden for as long as possible.

Comment: Note: submarines are *small* places with lots of people.  Expect to have to remain in a few square feet for the entire time.  The instant you move out (such as to use the bathroom), you'll run into someone.

Comment: I don't see a worldbuilding aspect to this question. You're asking for a hiding place for a specific character on an existing vessel.

Comment: You should include a few more details, such as, what kind of submarine? Big nuclear naval sub? Personal mini sub? What's the crew like? For instance, If the sub is big enough to have a head, and there is a crew of 1 or 2, then someone could sneak in and hide in the head, and not be discovered until someone needs to go to the bathroom. If it's a big sub, someone might be able to dress up as a sailor and hide in a storage closet or something and not be found for a while if they're careful.

Comment: Grab onto the outside and hold your breath for a very, very long time. It worked for Indiana Jones.

Answer (score 7):

**I'm inclined to say it cannot be done.**

Subs are never unattended. When not in the dock being prepared for a mission, they are on a mission. Full of people at any one time. Crew is known to sleep on board.

> I’d spend eighteen hours a day in the dry dock. If I could I would go home, but I slept onboard a lot just to get the extra hour of sleep.

Subs are small and do not have unused space at all. It would be poor design if they had. Especially when launching for a mission, even douche cabins are filled with supplies. Items like packaging cardboard gets left of the dock.

> Unlike surface ships, submarines are almost never resupplied at sea. They begin their patrol with a full load of foodstuffs and other supplies adequate for the crew. The limited available space in a submarine means that all unnecessary packaging material must be eliminated. Cardboard boxes are unpacked, and the cardboard is left at the dock.

No locked space at all. If entrance is controlled such spaces are attended by crew at all time. Safety regulations apply for checking any and all spaces continuously as well.

> Thats not the only reason.  There is no unused space aboard a submarine. 
>   Important valves, hull fitting, equipment controllers, stores lockers, etc 
>   are located in every space.  Underway watches must check many items to 
>   unsure that the boat is safe

The crew all know one another, by the end of the mission even by smell, and do not have any private space at all. The best you can get is the so-called rack (or bunk) where you sleep. For all but the largest subs these racks are shared by people on different shifts so can be occupied at any one time.

> boomer crews don't
>   even have to hot-bunk:  there's more than enough space for each man
>   to have his own bunk.

Imaginable you can sneak on board while in dock. You might even stash yourself in an unattended rack on a large sub. But once the sub is starting to get under way you will have better luck attaching yourself to the outside with hefty breathing equipment.
[gross]

> Two people sneaking off to f**k are going to get caught. There’s no place to hide.

References:
http://www.nap.edu/read/9190/chapter/10
http://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/confessions-of-a-u-s-navy-submarine-officer-1715113243
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.military.naval/1aZ75jHX1TY/g9mbG1n4bWcJ
Concepts In Submarine Design By Roy Burcher, Louis Rydill

Comment: I'd tend to agree, I don't see it happening unless you hide in plain sight by using deception.

Comment: Additionally, many subs only port at their home port. They go out on patrol and come back 6 months later. They are not like surface ships where they hit ports all over the world and stuff, subs mostly go out, hide, come back. So stowing away doesn't get you much.

Comment: What about the torpedo tubes?  Are they normally loaded when there's nobody about?  (And yes, they're very cramped!)

Comment: @LorenPechtel They're not generally kept loaded for ease of maintenance, but they're also not generally left open...  So you're going to need just as much breathing equipment as you would just magneting yourself to the hull, plus you have to figure out how to get in without setting off any alarms...  Both the inner and the outer doors have warning lamps that someone is probably watching.

Answer (score 3):

If they have some contacts in the base they could sneak on board on a fake torpedo (assuming this is a military vessel and of sufficient size to have torpedoes that large, which would be a big submarine), with screws/releases on the inside and the gear packed with the individual.

As the supply boxes are [fairly small it seems](http://webzoom.freewebs.com/henry0077/Food%20Pallet.jpg), and seem to be loaded individually I doubt your person could sneak on board here.

They probably don't want to puncture the hull, and the door is too easy to guard/watch to just walk on board, so the only other option I can see would be to impersonate a crew member, and hopefully exploit regularly shifting crews (if the organization that owns this submarine *has* regularly shifting crews).

Answer (score 2):

Fake paperwork to BE A CREWMEMBER. Even subs have folks rotate in and out. They are constantly short-handed and a last minute assignment would be welcome. Obviously even a rudimentary skills test would reveal the stowaway (as well as a lack of knowledge of submarine layouts, culture, and possibly military protocol entirely) but depending on how much "prep time" the stowaway has they could fake it, especially as a new sailor without their dolphin pin (http://navyformoms.com/forum/topics/dolphin-qualifications).

If you had to physically hide, your best bet is someplace not used while the sub is in port. Maybe in the galley storeroom? Someplace in the sonar room? Heck, maybe the galley OVEN if it is large enough? Most spaces are packed pretty full but with thermal insulation maybe in one of the reefer lockers. No crew member has a private room aside from the Captain and even he probably doesn't have a closet or anything large enough for a person.

"In and out" personnel accountability is one of the primary tasks for crewmembers guarding the (very few) access points on a sub, so if someone goes in and doesn't come out, they will be missed and searched for. Sailors will know of any private, remote places to hide on their sub because they probably use them themselves for stashing contraband :P

Answer (score 1):

Get in disguised as a civilian maintenance contractor. You will need to forge papers to be allowed in, perhaps you can also forge papers to show that you left again.

After your work, try to get out of sight. Depending on the technology of the sub, there might be bilge spaces or battery compartments. Or an escape trunk. But there is a high likelihood that someone will look in for routine maintenance. On a big sub, several allies in the galley staff might help you to hide in the pantry.

Do not try to mix with the general crew. A sub is small enough that the petty officers will know everybody on sight.